Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MapFieldReflectionAccessor
I am trying to call vertex AI and retrieve the data based on the query using java but getting the error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MapFieldReflectionAccessor"

I have tried by changing different versions of the dependencies but it is not working.
Also I have observed that MapFieldReflectionAccessor is deprecated and no more is used but I am getting this error only.
package com.multi_turn
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.EndpointName;
import com.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictResponse;
import com.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictionServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictionServiceSettings;
import com.google.protobuf.Value;
/*import com.google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.Value;*/
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;

public class PredictTextPromptSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String instance = "{ \"prompt\": " + "\"Give me ten interview questions for the role of program manager.\"}";
        
        System.out.println("Instance: " + instance);
        
        String parameters = "{\n" + "  \"temperature\": 0.2,\n" + "  \"maxOutputTokens\": 256,\n"
                + "  \"topP\": 0.95,\n" + "  \"topK\": 40\n" + "}";
    
        String project = "repl-template-test";
        String location = "us-central1";
        String publisher = "google";
        String model = "text-bison@001";
    
        predictTextPrompt(instance, parameters, project, location, publisher, model);
    
    }
    
    public static void predictTextPrompt(String instance, String parameters, String project, String location,
            String publisher, String model) throws IOException {
    
        String endpoint = String.format("%s-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443", location);
        PredictionServiceSettings predictionServiceSettings = PredictionServiceSettings.newBuilder()
                .setEndpoint(endpoint).build();
        try {
            PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.create(predictionServiceSettings);
            final EndpointName endPointName = EndpointName.ofProjectLocationPublisherModelName(project, location,
                    publisher, model);
    
            Value.Builder instanceValue = Value.newBuilder();
            JsonFormat.parser().merge(parameters, instanceValue);
            List<Value> instances = new ArrayList<Value>();
            instances.add(instanceValue.build());
    
            Value.Builder parameterValueBuilder = Value.newBuilder();
            JsonFormat.parser().merge(parameters, parameterValueBuilder);
            Value parameterValue = parameterValueBuilder.build();
    
            PredictResponse predictResponse = client.predict(endPointName, instances, parameterValue);
            System.out.println(predictResponse);
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    
    }

}

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>multi-turn_replit</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertex.ai</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vertex.ai</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-aiplatform</artifactId>
            <version>3.47.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

I should get the response from vertex AI instead of the error Im getting. It seems there is a compatibility issues of the versions of protobuf-java and google-cloud-aiplatform but not sure what to do.

NoClassDefFoundError means (in your case) that class MapFieldReflectionAccessor was accessible when your [Java] program was compiled but it is not accessible when you run your program. You need to compare the "build" path with the "runtime" path.
